# Can I prevent #div anchoring on a page when using idTabs for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the ***idTabs*** plugin for *jQuery* on my new site. However, when I try to select a specific tab via the url, say *http://crnaz.com/a/about/**#staff*** on page load or via tab navigation, the page anchors to the div *#staff* instead of page top.

Is there a way to keep the page anchored to the top on url change?

Here's the code (or you can view the source of the page http://crnaz.com/a/about/index.php). Thanks in advance for the help! :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

var start = location.hash;
  start = start?start.substr(1):0;
  $(".usual").tabs(true,start);

```
<div class="usual"> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#values">Values</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#theology">Theology</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#nazarene">Nazarene</a></li>
    <li><a href="#staff">Staff</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul> 
  <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div id="values" style="display: block; ">Tab Content</div>
      <div id="theology" style="display: block; ">Tab Content</div>
      <div id="nazarene" style="display: block; ">Tab Content</div>
      <div id="staff" style="display: block; ">Tab Content</div>
      <div id="contact" style="display: block; ">Tab Content</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks like this is default behaviour of the control you are using. Possibly the code will put the focus on the div, which in case it is bigger than the window it will scroll down a bit (to top of the div will be in the top of the window). To fix this you might need to dig into the code of the component (if you understand what the code is doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, you might try to trigger

```
$("html").scrollTop();
```

after pageload.